# MYSQL Table creation & index for huge table

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have a peculiar situation that brings me to you for advice, as this is the first time in quite a while where I don't have a clue where to start.

I have a large database of records with a single table that contains about 700k rows. The table is mostly text strings with a lot of indexes, as there's many ways to interface with the data on our website.

I am attempting to build a single tool that sound very simple:

In this table there is a column called business_codes.

This table includes a series of two-digit strings separated by a tilde "~".

Now this column cannot be NULL, thus it always has at least a single two-digit string for each record.

We have a job that updates these records directly from our vendor each hour via cron & some PHP.

The tool I am trying to create will pull the strings for each record, then cross-reference each one with all the other records in the database & return the amount of times it was used.

For instance. You login to the site, and you check this tool.

Your own business_codes in the database are AB~CD~EF

I want the tool to sort through each of your business_codes and output suggested business_codes to add to your profile based on the use of other records with the same business code.

The tool would look up each of your own codes and result:

84% of other business_codes with with AB in their profile also use HI
77% of other business_codes with with CD in their profile also use LM

This is absolute madness. My first stab at it was to create a metadata table and import the codes into the new table individually without the ~.

I can write the PHP to display all of this, my question is on the structure of the table (if a table even needs to be created). I am at a loss on how to even approach this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store lists in a delimited string!  Use a proper association table, with one row per business and per tag.

Comment: It may help if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and use the actual columns names and queries for explaining the problem.